# Is a product backlog related with the domain model?

Tags: scrum, ddd-repositories

Is a product backlog related with the domain model in a DDD aproach or I'm mixing unrelated concepts?

Comment: You're linking a design approach (how) with a business artifact (what) but they're two different concepts. The PO will express their ideas, concerns, desires in the backlog and the Dev team can approach whatever they think it's the best solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question. It might be on-topic at [pm.se] (but read their help first)

Comment: It is a programming question, it can be considered architecture or development and there is nothing about project management, there is no project management like PMBOK in Scrum. I questioned about the relationship when you create the domain and the models, and Maarten was very clear about my question!

Answer (score 1):

Scrum doesn't prescribe *exactly* how you express Product Backlog Items. You can use User Stories, Job Stories or your own custom thing. As long as your Product Backlog Items have the following attributes (from the Scrum Guide):

*"The Product Backlog lists all features, functions, requirements, enhancements, and fixes that constitute the changes to be made to the product in future releases. Product Backlog items have the attributes of a description, order, estimate, and value. Product Backlog items often include test descriptions that will prove its completeness when "Done"."* - Scrum Guide

How these Product Backlog Items are picked up and broken down in smaller chunks of work in the Sprint, is up to the Development Team. They can use whatever approach they want. As long as the resulting chunks of work are small enough to fit in a Sprint.